# Function call and pass value in the same OnClick - React

Tags: reactjs

I got a OnClick which actually receives an id:

```
<Button onClick={() => addToCart(id)} >Buy</Button>
```

On the other hand, in a different JS file,I got a modal which appears with a click via useState:

```
const [stateModal1, changeModalState1] = useState(false);
```

Now, in the same component I work with this modal, I map an array which returns a Button, which now is working with the "addToCart(id)" value mentioned before, like this:

```
{products.map((product) => {
       return <Product image={product.image} 
       key={product.id} 
       data={product} 
       addToCart={() =>addToCart(product.id)} />})}
```

The question that is driving me crazy is: how can I use the button in the mapped array to trigger that modal, and at the same time, to pass values to that modal in order to show the mapped item IN that modal?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is the modal, which is another component:

```
const Modal = ({
    children, 
    state, 
    stateModal1, 
    })

return (
        <>
            {state && 

            <Overlay>
                <Container>
                    <CloseButton onClick={() => changeState(false)}>{FaWindowClose}</CloseButton >
                    {children}
                    <Header>
                        <h3>Confirm buy</h3>
                        <h4>{name}</h4>
                        <h4>$ {price}</h4>
                    </Header>
                    <Button onClick={() => changeState(false)}>Confirm</Button>
                </Container>
            </Overlay>
            }
        </>)
```

PS: the "confirm" button which triggers the "changeState()", should also trigger the addToCart().

Comment: Hi and welcome.
It would be really helpful if you provide modal component too.
Thanks

Comment: thank you for your reply. Edit made.

Comment: whats the component structure? is the <modal /> component a child of <product /> or a sibling of it?

Comment: sibling. It is not inside.

Comment: then i think you can lift up the state to <modal /> parent component and control the state whenever you click a <product /> and pass the product info as props to <modal /> at the same time

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: <Products>
const [open, setOpen]=useState(false); //modal state
const [selectedProduct, setSelectProduct]=useState(null); //selected product

const addToCart = (id)=>{
const product = products.filter(...); // retrieve the selected product based on id
setSelectProduct(product); 
setOpen(true);
}

{products.map((product) => {
       return <Product image={product.image} 
       key={product.id} 
       data={product} 
       addToCart={() =>addToCart(product.id)} />})}
{open&&<Modal product={selectedProduct} onClose={handleClose} onConfirm={handleConfirm}/>}
</Products>

Comment: in this way, using props to share data between components. also you can use context or redux to share the data between different components. all up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by other comments above, you can pass a prop to the modal component from the parent component to achieve your demand normally.

The only thing that needs to be done is set the open/close modal state and the passing data state at the same time, or, probably use one state directly

sample of the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Modal } from "antd";

export default function App() {

  // init with undefined, if not undefined, open the modal
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(undefined);
  
  const list = [...Array(20).keys()];
  
  // set the state to open the modal, as well as pass it to the modal itself as a prop if necessary
  const handleClick = (idx) => () => {
    setModal(idx);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map((x, idx) => (
        <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} onClick={handleClick(idx)}>
          {x}
        </div>
      ))}
      <Modal visible={modal !== undefined}>The value you passed: {modal}</Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the online demo could be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shape-89y78?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This couldn't be clearer! Thank you very much, this answers me a lot of questions I didn't even make, including the one I posted.